# Script or command to get a user's memory consumption

Tags: python, unix, memory

My host is offering me a limited amount of RAM for my websites and I would like to monitor the memory consumption by running a script in the cron.

I have made up this command:

```
ps -u xxxxxx -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'
```

But the way my host is calculating memory has a particularity. It ignores processes that runs for less than 5 minutes.

Do you know of a command or Python script that can show me the total used memory ignoring short lived processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `etime` to find the elapsed time of a process. You can then modify your `awk` command to check if this time is greater than 5 mins.

```
ps -u xxxxxx -o rss,etime,command | ...
```

The format of elapsed time is `[[dd-]hh:]mm:ss`. This means the time could be 00:30, 12:57:39 or even 4-08:27:12. You can use `awk` to parse this time format and convert it into seconds. Once in seconds, check if it is more than 5 minutes, and if so add it to the running total of rss.

Here is a sample script which does this:

```
ps -u xxxxxx -o rss,etime,command | grep -v peruser | grep -v RSS | sed 's/^ *//g' | awk '{
 split($2,arr,":") #split time on :
 len=0
 for(i in arr) len++ 
 secs=arr[len]+60*arr[len-1] #convert to seconds
 if(len>2) secs=secs+substr(arr[len-2],length(arr[len-2])-1)*60*60

 if(secs>5*60) { #check if more than 5 minutes
     print $0 #print out the process
     sum+=$1 
 }
} END{print "SUM:"sum/1024}'
```

Comment: I really suck at unix commands :( Can you please tell me how to modify my awk command and filter out processes with a an etime of 5 minutes or less? Thank you!

Comment: Damnit, I did not get the notification of your answer. I'll test you script right away and post my results tomorrow. Thanks dogbane!